# For quantum particle with quantum number $$ in an infinite square well are these statement correct

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I was wondering if the following statements are correct for a quantum particle in infinite square well

1. The greater $$, the greater average kinetic energy associated with this wave function.
2. In the limit of high quantum numbers, the quantum mechanical result reduces to its classical counterpart in the classical domain.
3. We will finally get a classical probability density if $n$ gets greater.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kinetic energy is proportional to the *curvature* of the wave function, and indeed the larger $n$ gets the larger the curvature of the wave function, which implies that the kinetic energy becomes larger.

The quantum probability distribution does approach a uniform distribution in the limit of large $n$, so you can think of this as a "classical distribution", although note that this comes with many caveats (e.g. classically we can know the exact position and momentum of the particle at any point, so in principle there is no need for a probability distribution).

Some time ago I prepared some interactive code that you can use to visualize the wave function for the infinite square well for different values of $n$, you can find it in this [Jupyter Notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/profmscience/1d-potentials/blob/master/infinite-square-well.ipynb).